# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.setAttribute

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, nullpointerexception

Here is my code:

```
   public class SiteAnalizer extends HttpServlet {

    private static final String[] symbols = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h",
        "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&",
        "*", "~", "?" };
    private HashMap wordMap;
    PrintWriter pw;
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    private HttpServletResponse response;
    private StringBuffer hashIndex = new StringBuffer();
    private int percentage;
    private int pageNumber=0;;
    LinkedList<DataHolder> storeDataHolders = new LinkedList<DataHolder>();
    int primaryKey = 0;
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 1;
    int count = 0;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        doPost(request,response);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException
    {

        this.request = request;
        this.response = response;

        String[] listOfWords = request.getParameter("wordList").toLowerCase().trim().split("\n"); //Get the List of words
        percentage = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("percentage")); // Get the percentage value
        double numberOfWordsInProgramHash = 0; //Keep track of how many words in "program" per webpage
         //Store the primary key



        StringBuilder userListWithoutDuplicates = new StringBuilder();

        pw = response.getWriter();

        double numberOfKnownWords = 0;


        Arrays.sort(listOfWords);

        //Remove the duplicated words in user's list
        HashSet<String> userDefinedSet = new HashSet<String>();

        for(int i=0;i<listOfWords.length;i++)
        {
            if (!userDefinedSet.contains(listOfWords[i].trim())) 
            {
                userListWithoutDuplicates.append(listOfWords[i].trim());
                userListWithoutDuplicates.append(" ");
            userDefinedSet.add(listOfWords[i].trim());

                //pw.println(listOfWords[i].trim());
        }
        }

        //createHashForUserList(userListWithoutDuplicates);
        hashIndex = createHashForUserList(userListWithoutDuplicates);


        //Read the Hash File
        String str = "";
        String fileName = "C:/Users/Yohan/Desktop/Test.txt";


        BlockingQueue<String> fileContent = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
        BigFileReader bigFileReader = new BigFileReader(fileName, fileContent);
        BigFileProcessor bigFileProcessor = new BigFileProcessor(fileContent);
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);
        es.execute(bigFileReader);
        es.execute(bigFileProcessor);
        es.shutdown();



    }

    /*
     * This method is responsible for creating the Hash List for the entire list of words
     * we have, and creating the Hash for the User desined word list
     * */
    private StringBuffer createHashForUserList(StringBuilder userListWithoutDuplicates)
    {
        System.out.println("Calling createHashForUserList()");

        createWordNumberingMap();

        String[]finalWordHolder = userListWithoutDuplicates.toString().split(" ");
        StringBuffer hashIndex = new StringBuffer();

        //Navigate through text and create the Hash
    for(int arrayCount=0;arrayCount<finalWordHolder.length;arrayCount++)
    {

         if(wordMap.containsKey(finalWordHolder[arrayCount]))
         {
            hashIndex.append((String)wordMap.get(finalWordHolder[arrayCount]));
                hashIndex.append(" ");
         }

    }

        //pw.println(hashIndex.toString());


        return hashIndex;
    }



    //Hash Generating Algorithm
    public static String getSequence(final int i) {
    return symbols[i / (symbols.length * symbols.length)] + symbols[(i / symbols.length) % symbols.length]
            + symbols[i % symbols.length];
    }


    //Create Hashes for each word in Word List
    private Map createWordNumberingMap()
    {
        int number = 0;
        wordMap = new HashMap();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String str = "";

        //First Read The File
        File readingFile = new File("D:/Eclipse WorkSpace EE/HashCreator/WordList/NewWordsList.txt");
        try
        {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(readingFile));
            while((str=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                  str = str.trim();
                  String id = getSequence(number);
                  wordMap.put(str,id);
                  number++;
                  System.out.println(id);

            }

            br.close();
            System.out.println("Completed");
            System.out.println(wordMap.get("000"));
            System.out.println("Last Number: "+number);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                    br.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return wordMap;
    }


    //Processor
    private class BigFileProcessor implements Runnable 
    {
        private final BlockingQueue<String> linesToProcess;
        double numberOfWordsInProgramHash = 0; //Keep track of how many words in "program" per webpage
        double numberOfKnownWords = 0;


        public BigFileProcessor (BlockingQueue<String> linesToProcess) 
        {
            this.linesToProcess = linesToProcess;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            String line = "";
            try 
            {
                while ( (line = linesToProcess.take()) != null) 
                {
                    if(line==BigFileReader.SENTINEL)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    System.out.println(count);
                    count++;

                    HashSet<String>hashSet = new HashSet<String>();
                    ArrayList<String>matchingWordsHolder = new ArrayList<String>();
                    ArrayList<String>unmatchingWordsHolder = new ArrayList<String>();

                    int lastIndex = 0;


                    for(int i=0;i<=line.length();i=i+3)
                    {
                        lastIndex = i;
                        try
                        {
                            String stringPiece = line.substring(i, i+3);
                            //  pw.println(stringPiece);
                            hashSet.add(stringPiece);
                        }
                        catch(Exception arr)
                        {
                            String stringPiece = line.substring(lastIndex, line.length());
                            //  pw.println(stringPiece);
                            hashSet.add(stringPiece);
                        }
                    }

                    numberOfWordsInProgramHash = hashSet.size();
                    //pw.println("HASH sets size: "+numberOfWordsInProgramHash);

                    //Create the Hash for the user input
                    String[] finalUserDefinedWordCollection = hashIndex.toString().trim().split(" ");

                    //Check how many words exists
                    for(int i=0;i<finalUserDefinedWordCollection.length;i++)
                    {

                        if(hashSet.contains(finalUserDefinedWordCollection[i]))
                        {
                            matchingWordsHolder.add(finalUserDefinedWordCollection[i]);
                            //pw.println(finalUserDefinedWordCollection[i]);
                            hashSet.remove(finalUserDefinedWordCollection[i]);
                            numberOfKnownWords++;
                        }

                    }

                    //Making a list of words do not exists
                    Iterator iter = hashSet.iterator();
                    //pw.println("Words which do not exists");
                     //pw.println("..................");
                    //pw.println("HashSet size after existing words removed: "+hashSet.size());

                    while(iter.hasNext())
                    {
                        //pw.println(iter.next().toString());
                        // pw.write(" ");
                        unmatchingWordsHolder.add(iter.next().toString());
                    }

                    double matchingPercentage = ((numberOfKnownWords/numberOfWordsInProgramHash)*100.0);
                    //pw.println("Page No: "+pageNumber+"  Number Of Matches: "+numberOfKnownWords+"   Matching Percentage: "+String.valueOf(matchingPercentage));
                    //pw.println();


                    if(matchingPercentage>percentage)
                    {
                        DataHolder data = new DataHolder();

                        data.setOriginalHash(line);
                        data.setPrimaryKey(pageNumber);

                        StringBuffer matchingWordsStr = new StringBuffer("");
                        StringBuffer unMatchingWordsStr = new StringBuffer("");

                        //Populating Strings
                        for(int m=0;m<matchingWordsHolder.size();m++)
                        {

                            Iterator iterInWordMap = wordMap.entrySet().iterator();

                            while(iterInWordMap.hasNext())
                            {
                                Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry)iterInWordMap.next();

                                if(mEntry.getValue().equals(matchingWordsHolder.get(m)))
                                {
                                    //out.println(matchingWords.get(m)+" : "+true);
                                    matchingWordsStr.append(mEntry.getKey());
                                    matchingWordsStr.append(",");
                                }
                            }

                        }

                        data.setMatchingWords(matchingWordsStr);

                        for(int u=0;u<unmatchingWordsHolder.size();u++)
                        {
                            Iterator iterInWordMap = wordMap.entrySet().iterator();

                            while(iterInWordMap.hasNext())
                            {
                                Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry)iterInWordMap.next();

                                if(mEntry.getValue().equals(unmatchingWordsHolder.get(u)))
                                {
                                    //out.println(matchingWords.get(m)+" : "+true);
                                    unMatchingWordsStr.append(mEntry.getKey());
                                    unMatchingWordsStr.append(",");
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        data.setUnmatchingWords(unMatchingWordsStr);

                        storeDataHolders.add(data);
                        pw.write("Record Added to DataHolder");
                    }

                    numberOfKnownWords = 0;
                    primaryKey++;
                    pageNumber++;
                }
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    //Data Reader
    private class BigFileReader implements Runnable 
    {
        private final String fileName;
        int a = 0;
        public static final String SENTINEL = "SENTINEL";

        private final BlockingQueue<String> linesRead;

       public BigFileReader(String fileName, BlockingQueue<String> linesRead) 
       {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.linesRead = linesRead;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
        try {
            //since it is a sample, I avoid the manage of how many lines you have read
            //and that stuff, but it should not be complicated to accomplish
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("Test.txt")));
            String str = "";

            while((str=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                linesRead.put(str);
            }
            linesRead.put(SENTINEL);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Grab the first 1000 items from LinkedList
        List<DataHolder> firstTenItems = new ArrayList<DataHolder>();


        for(int i=0;i<storeDataHolders.size();i++)
        {
            firstTenItems.add(storeDataHolders.get(i));

            if(i==9)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        //Convert the Hashed words back to real words

       if(request==null)
       {
           System.out.println("Request is null");
       }
        request.setAttribute("list", firstTenItems);

        RequestDispatcher dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
            try {
                dispatch.forward(request, response);
            } catch (ServletException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }


    }
  }





}
```

The biggest issue with this code is it is getting `NullPointerException`. When the process is finished at the `Servlet`, it is supposed to redirect back to the `JSP`, it just display the Blank `Servlet`. But it is not happening, due to this issue. Below is the error code.

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.setAttribute(Request.java:1563)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.setAttribute(RequestFacade.java:543)
    at analyzer.SiteAnalizer$BigFileReader.run(SiteAnalizer.java:413)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The NullPointerException is happening in the below piece of code

```
request.setAttribute("list", firstTenItems);
```

It seems like that `firstTenItems` is not null because the below code is not printing the message

```
 if(firstTenItems==null)
   {
       System.out.println("First Ten Items Null");
   }
```

So what has gone wrong here?

**Update**

Here is the web.xml if required

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SiteAnalizer</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>analyzer.SiteAnalizer</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SiteAnalizer</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/SiteAnalizer</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

**Update**

I tried adding `pw.println("This is working")` right above the redirection code lines. It also did not get printed, something else is happening! But if I use `System.out.println("This is working")` there, I can see it in Netbeans log!

**Update**

Here is the Server.xml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container", 
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-" 
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->           
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the 
         connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
         described in the APR documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">         
    --> 
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->        

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: seems like `request` is null, Why don't you pass the `request` object to the `BigFileReader` via constructor?

Comment: @sanbhat - `request` can't be `null`. The NPE is thrown from within `Request.setAttribute`.

Comment: Are you sure you know where System.out is going?  Change the test from an if statement to "System.out.println("********" + firstTenItems)" so you will get something printed whether or not it is null.

Comment: Which version of tomcat are you using?

Comment: @raVan: I think 6 or  7

Comment: Please check the exact version. Do you have any listeners registered?

Comment: Yes, please provide the exact version. Also, provide the registered listener information.

Comment: @raVan: Version 7.0.22. For listeners, please see the updated question, I have added the `web.xml`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Version 7.0.22. For listeners, please see the updated question, I have added the `web.xml`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I made another update. Please have a look.

Comment: @raVan: I made another update. Please have a look.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: May I post the complete code if it helps?

Comment: @raVan: May I post the complete code if it helps?

Comment: I believe your Context is not getting set. Can you provide the server.xml?

Comment: @raVan: I updated the exisintg code with the complete code. Please have a look.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis:I updated the exisintg code with the complete code. Please have a look.

Comment: You have pasted the context.xml and not the server.xml :)

Comment: @raVan: Sorry, I corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that your are taking the `HttpServletRequest` received in the `doPost()` method, storing it in an instance variable and trying to reuse it later. **Don't ever do this.** The life cycle of a request is the duration of the `Servlet#service(..)` call. After that, it no longer, conceptually, exists.

Specifically, Tomcat reuses its `HttpServletRequest` objects. When your code returns from its `doPost(..)` and then from the `HttpServlet#service(..)` method, the Servlet container recycles the `HttpServletRequest` it passed as an argument to your method. Part of this recycling process, a call to [`recycle()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.22/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java#Request.recycle%28%29), is to set one of its fields to `null`. This field that gets set to `null` causes your `NullPointerException`. You can see the source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.22/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java#Request.setAttribute%28java.lang.String,java.lang.Object%29).

```
1563        Object listeners[] = context.getApplicationEventListeners();
```

In the line above, `context` is `null`, because the `HttpServletRequest` was recycled.

If there are things you need to do with the `HttpServletRequest` either don't do it in a separate thread or do it in an [asynchronous context](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077995/java-concurrency/asynchronous-processing-support-in-servlet-3-0.html). If you're going to keep using the `HttpServletRequest`, you cannot have finished processing the HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

The `request` is not multi-thread safe and two threads are writing to it concurrently. As a result, storing the `firstTenItems` container to the request object results in a `NulllPointerException` during the save to an internal data-structure within the `Request` object. To correct this, you can change `NUMBER_OF_THREADS=1`, or properly synchronize access the `request` object.

Note that `storeDataHolders` is only initialized; the container is empty. As a result, your intended copy of first ten elements is completing trivially, without a loop.

When `request.setAttribute("list", firstTenItems)` is invoked from multiple threads with two different `firstTenItems` objects, the shared `request` object tries to serialize that to the `"list"` attribute which results in a `NullPointerException` as a result of two threads overwriting the same attribute with two different values.

Comment: What do you make of `LinkedList<DataHolder> storeDataHolders = new LinkedList<DataHolder>();`?

Comment: And what serialization are you talking about?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the `storeDataHolders` is an initialized container into which nothing is ever added.

Comment: I still don't see why that's an issue. `firstTenItems` is not `null`, it's just empty.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis by "serialize" I mean store to the internal data structure. It's correct that `firstTenItems` is not `null` but it is the subsequent storage of two distict `firstTenItems` objects to the same `request` object's internal data structure that causes the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: How and why? Prove it to us.

Comment: But you might be correct about threading. Can you show me how to do this?

Comment: May I suggest, @GloryOfSuccess, that you write a JUnit test containing the "interesting" code, i.e., everything but the web-container and web-interactions. Build an API which does this interesting work and show that it works within a JUnit test with many threads before you add that code to a container. In my experience, this is a much faster way to solve these types of problems.

Comment: I still don't see how two threads storing different values in the `Request` causes a `NullPointerException`.